# Consider the sequence ${a_n}: a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2,$ and $a_n = 2a_{n−1} + a_{n−2}$ for n ≥ 3. Prove that k ∈ N, $2^k | a_n$ if and only if $2^k | n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I've been working on the problem:

> Consider the sequence ${a_n}: a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2,$ and $a_n = 2a_{n−1} + a_{n−2}$ for n ≥ 3. Prove that k ∈ N, $2^k | a_n$ if and only if $2^k | n$

I've programmed and found some properties:

1. $a_{n}\equiv a_{n-2^k} \pmod {2^k}$
2. $a_{2^k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^k}$

I don't know how to prove them but I'm able to show that:
$$\begin{aligned}
a_n &= 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \\
     &= a_2a_{n-1}+a_1a_{n-2} \\
     &=a_2(2a_{n-2}+a_{n-3})+a_1a_{n-2} \\
&=a_3a_{n-2}+a_2a_{n-3} \\
&=a_ja_{n+1-j}+a_{j-1}a_{n-j} &(2 \leq j\leq n-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Is that the correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: From [How to ask a good a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title.
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: Can you solve the recurrence?

Comment: Yes, I've got $a_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+\sqrt 2)^k(1-\sqrt 2)^{n-1-k}$

Comment: You may find$$a_n=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$$more useful.

Comment: So I should expand $a_n$ with binomial theorem?